# What is the name of this filter

Tags: filters

Let's $q(t)\in \mathbb{R}$ represents a noisy raw signal, the filter is
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{x}_1 &= x_2 + g\gamma_1(q-x_1) \\
\dot{x}_2 &= g^2\gamma_2(q-x_1)
\end{align}
$$
where $x_1$ represents the smoothed version of $q$ and $x_2$ represents an estimate for $\dot{q}$ and $g$ is the filter's gain. The constants $\gamma_{1,2}$ are positive constants. What is the name of this filter and how it works?

Comment: What is the filter's input, and what is its output? Where is the independent variable (time)? What is $q$ and what is its "smoothed version"?

Comment: @MBaz the raw signal $q(t)$ is the input. The outputs are $x_{1,2}$. The smoothed version is preventing higher frequencies.

Comment: Do you mean that the outputs are the $x$s with dots? And, if there are two outputs, don't you have two filters?

Comment: @MBaz the outputs are $x_{1,2}$ and because they are coupled I believe this is a one filter but I'm not sure since I'm asking what is this filter?

Comment: @MBaz you could simulate it by adding some noise to $q(t)$ and you will see it is working good (i.e. you can integrate $\dot{x}_{1,2}$ to obtain $x_{1,2}$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid there is no special designation for the parameters you indicate.

Your expression describes a **Second Order Band Pass Filter**, which is clearer by taking its State Space form, and making some notation and variable changes:
$$
\dot{\left[\begin{array}{cc}x_1 \\x_2 \end{array}\right]}
=\left[\begin{array}{cc}-a_1 & 1\\-a_2 & 0\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}x_1 \\x_2 \end{array}\right]
+\left[\begin{array}{cc}a_1 \\a_2 \end{array}\right]
u
$$

After taking into Laplace Domain and doing some matrices, we have exposed the Transfer Functions:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}x_1 \\x_2 \end{array}\right]
={1 \over s^2+a_1s+a_2}\left[\begin{array}{cc}s & 1\\-a_2 & s+a_1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}a_1 \\a_2 \end{array}\right]
u\\
=\left[\begin{array}{cc}{sa_1+a_2 \over s^2+a_1s+a_2}\\{sa_2 \over s^2+a_1s+a_2}\end{array}\right]
u
$$

As you see, the roots of $s^2+a_1s+a_2$ describe the poles of your Second Order System. Inspecting the Discriminant $\Delta$, you can check the poles will always be stable for $\gamma_i$ positive.
If $\Delta=g^2(\gamma_1^2-4\gamma_2)>0$ the poles will be real, and the sytem will be *Overdamped*.

If $\Delta=g^2(\gamma_1^2-4\gamma_2)<0$, the poles will be complex, the system will be *Underdamped*, and we can calculate natural frequency $\omega$ and damping $\zeta$:
$$
\omega=g\sqrt{\gamma_2}\\
\zeta={\gamma_1 \over 2 \sqrt{\gamma_2}}
$$

The zeros for $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $g\gamma_1/\gamma_2$ and $0$ respectively. And since we have only a Order 2, care should be taken to determine the cut frequencies for the bandpass.

Comment: but why $x_2$ represents the first derivative? First derivative in Laplace transform is only $s$ but I see in your answer it is a polynomial of second degree.

Comment: Exactly. The algebra is not lying, there is not a derivative in there. Unless you start adding some additional conditions, such as $u(t)$ moves very slowly in order their frequency components are very small with respect to the poles frequencies, then $s^2+a_1s+a_2 \approx a_2$ and only so, under that specific consideration, you might say, $$x_2(t)\approx {sa_2 \over a_2}u(t)={d \over dt}u(t)$$

Comment: so it is an estimate not first derivative so to speak, right?

Comment: Though there is no reason in here to estimate a derivative, since having the signal, there is nothing preventing you to simply compute it, but yes.

Comment: interesting, I've seen this filter is being used in robotics with relatively high frequency where encoders provide noisy measurements.

Comment: Nice answer well done.

Comment: When you have some model of the frequency response of the noise, then yes, you can pertinently design a bandpass for that noise, and then, apply a derivative